# 404 Prevention in Wordpress by checking DB first then going to proper folder

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I need to try to prevent 404s for a website as much as possible. Some of these are just typos or bad links. Some are just changes in their business links that happen all the time. I've tried making some of the code in htaccess smart about catching some of this stuff.

However, I have several 404s with pages that change often like this:

example.com/lorem-ipsum/directory/blahblah/
example.com/dolor-foo/directory/whatever/

So I'd like to make anything that has a 404 under
example.com/********/directory/#######/
go to
example.com/********/
however I think that has to be done in WP somehow as it needs to check the DB first then decide to redirect to that folder. Is there a way to do this?

I've tried this, but its not working:

```
function get_page_by_name($pagename)
{
    $pages = get_pages();

    foreach ($pages as $page)
    {
        if ($page->post_name == $pagename)
            return $page;
    }

    return false;
}



function smarter_404s($location, $status) {
    //if we get a 404 for a /whatever/directory/something or /whatever/directory/ then go to /whatever/ if it exists
    if ($status == 404) {
        $path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
        $path_parts = explode('/', path);

        if (!empty($path_parts[1])) {
            $page = get_page_by_name($path_parts[0]);//see if it exists

            if (!empty($page)) {
                //this page exists, so we can redirect to it
                return $location = '/' . $path_parts[0] . '/';//change the location
            }
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'wp_redirect', 'smarter_404s' );
```

Answer (score 0):

most of the stuff you're after is already being done by [wp-includes/canonical.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.1/src/wp-includes/canonical.php). hook onto the [redirect_canonical](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.1/src/wp-includes/canonical.php#L489) filter, make sure to call it as below so that you'll get access to the second `$requested_url` parameter

```
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', 'smarter_404s', 10, 2 );
```

[see here for explanation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97356/trouble-understanding-apply-filters)

modify your callback to accept the second argument like this

```
function smarter_404s( $redirect_url, $requested_url ) {
    if ( is_404() ) {
            //match $requested_url against your path pattern and return the url you want the user to be redirected to

    }
    return $redirect_url;
}
```

and return a redirect url of your choice in the `if` block.

**Update**

however, the above only works for partial URL matches. you'll have to hook onto the [template_redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) action hook to catch the rest

```
function smarter_404s( $redirect_url, $requested_url = '' ) {
    if ( is_404() ) {
        //if $requested_url is empty the call came from the template_redirect hook
        if( empty( $requested_url ) ) {
            //match REQUEST_URI and do your redirect using wp_redirect
            wp_redirect( 'http://example.com/foo' );
            exit();
        }
        //match $requested_url against your path pattern
        //and return the url you want the user to be redirected to
        return 'http://example.com/foo';
    }
    return $redirect_url;    
}
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', 'smarter_404s', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'smarter_404s' );
```

`template_redirect` does not pass a second argument, and it doesn't care about returned values since it's an action hook. so you can use the same callback by giving `$requested_url` a default value if you want, but this will lead to a nested `if` block.